# Basic authentication doesn't work for SOAP Web Service with Active Directory LDAP in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, active-directory, ldap, soapui, spring-security-ldap

The HTTP Basic Authentication is failing while testing the SOAP Request from SOAP UI but working when trying to access the wsdl from Web Browser.

I have added the Authentication details in SOAP UI also under Authentication tab with details as shown below:

1. Authorization Type  : Global HTTP Basic
2. Username : ****
3. Password : ****
4. Domain: test.com //here the domain given which has configured in LDAP Config

Getting below error logs on consoile while testing from SOAP UI:

```
Getting " ExceptionTranslationFilter - Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point 
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied 
" 
[DEBUG] 2018-08-28 12:08:33.070 [http-nio-36454-exec-3] AndRequestMatcher - Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**', GET] 
[DEBUG] 2018-08-28 12:08:33.070 [http-nio-36454-exec-3] AntPathRequestMatcher - Request 'POST /error' doesn't match 'GET /** 
[DEBUG] 2018-08-28 12:08:33.070 [http-nio-36454-exec-3] AndRequestMatcher - Did not match 
[DEBUG] 2018-08-28 12:08:33.070 [http-nio-36454-exec-3] HttpSessionRequestCache - Request not saved as configured RequestMatcher did not
```

## Config() as shown below:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);

        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);

    }
```

Anything need to be add in `WsConfigurerAdapter` class  apart from defaultWsdl11Definition for SOAP Web service call to Authenticate in Spring Boot?

and also added the below code in SOAPWebServiceConfig.java:

```
@Bean
    public XwsSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor(){
        XwsSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor = new XwsSecurityInterceptor();
        //Callback Handler -> SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler
        securityInterceptor.setCallbackHandler(callbackHandler());
        //Security Policy -> securityPolicy.xml
        securityInterceptor.setPolicyConfiguration(new ClassPathResource("securityPolicy.xml"));
        return securityInterceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler callbackHandler() {
        SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler handler = new SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler();
        handler.setUsersMap(Collections.singletonMap("user", "password"));
        return handler;
    }

    //Interceptors.add -> XwsSecurityInterceptor
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
        interceptors.add(securityInterceptor());
    }
```

Can anyone please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try using this in config():
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().csrf().disable().httpBasic();
    }

And when you said Basic Authentication, select "Basic" in SOAP UI Authorization.
```